# How to add custom jar with security Authentication providers in JBoss eap 7.1

Tags: security, authentication, jboss, migration, weblogic12c

I am in the process of migrating web application from Weblogic 12c to JBoss EAP 7.1. 
In Weblogic is used the default security realm "myrealm" with WebLogic Adjudication, Authentication, Identity Assertion, Authorization, Role Mapping, and Credential Mapping providers configured by default. 
But also in "myrealm" section "Authentication" was added custom provider, simply by copying jar to the folder in wlsserver (..Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\mbeantypes). 
Is it possible to add this jar with providers in JBoss EAP 7.1. and how?

Answer (score 0):

These security providers use WebLogic APIs and then are not deployable to JBoss or another J2EE application server.